# How to update a table in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table named "State" in my database "sensorvalues". The table "State" has two columns. One is called "Device" and the other is called "Value". I am trying to use a GET request to update the value of "Fan" to be a value of "5". First I echo the GET variable of "5" on the web page to make sure my php file is receiving it, then I connect to the database. I am sure both these steps are correct. However, I am not able to take the variable $temp (this is where the GET data is saved into) and update it in the table for the Fan's value. This is the line of code I have after I save the variable into $temp and connect to the mysql database:

```
$sql = "UPDATE State SET Value=$temp WHERE Device='Fan'"
```

after this line of code, I close the mysql connection with

```
mysql_close($db)
```

However, after typing in "url?fan=5" I get the output 5 on the webpage but the table "State" still has the old value of the Fan. Why is this code not updating the database? I have tried it with both "Device=Fan" and Device='Fan'" along with "SET Value='$temp'" and "SET Value =$temp"

Comment: I think you must also add the lines, in which you're transferring $_GET data into variables

Comment: I do have a line of code that does that. Then I echo that variable to make sure it was saved into the variable correctly. The variable is being echoed so I know it is being saved properly

Comment: Have your used mysql_query() or anything else to execute your query ? It's not shown in above code.Please also share those lines of code, no one will assume that you'have done all that until you explicitly mention here.

Comment: You have to execute the query. Probably `mysql_query ($db, $sql);`

Comment: No, After I select the database do I do mysq_query() before the update line of code I have above?

Comment: @Dan Please share complete code !! The above given code is incomplete.

Comment: So all that `$sql = "...";` does is set a variable equal to that string of characters. Place the line of code I gave immediately after you assign the $sql variable. Also, you might want to look up some more basic tutorials on programming and php before you get into database usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the query as well-

```
// Update query
$sql = "UPDATE State SET Value=$temp WHERE Device='Fan'"

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully"; // show success message
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error; // show error message
}
$conn->close(); // optional, but recommended, connection close, is the $conn is the variable for the database connection
```

Do not mysql_* functions, use mysqli, or PDO instead.

This is the object oriented method, for the procedural method you can check out - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: I edited your code slightly to informative add comments and make sure that it is easily selected and easy to see, but nicely put. +1